# V(D)J recombination on homologous chromosome

Tags: immunology, chromosome

V(D)J recombination is known to recombine IG locus of a B cell. Is anything known about how the recombinations on two homologous chromosomes are connected? For example, are the selected V(D)J couples(triples) the same on both homologues?

Comment: I did not understand the *selected V(D)J couples(triples) the same on both homologues* part, but if you are asking about it's mechanism, then [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V(D)J_recombination), [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009286740200675X) and [this article](http://cellular-immunity.blogspot.in/2007/12/vdj-recombination.html) are places to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two alleles (variants of the same genetic region) for the Ig and TCR loci, one on each chromosome. The cell will try first with one allele to obtain a productive arrangement, and then with the other. If the cell fails on both alleles, the cell undergoes apoptosis. If at least one allele has a productive arrangement, the cells move on to selection.

Groups are still uncertain, however, how the cell chooses which allele to initiate recombination on, and ruled out parental imprinting as a culprit last year ([1](https://www.nature.com/articles/icb20171?WT.feed_name=subjects_molecular-biology)).

To be certain, the regions are the same, though not the same sequence. However, mechanisms during recombination ensure that recombination events among individual cells result in robust junctional diversity and a suitably diverse repertoire of immature antibody or TCR sequences ([example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/junctional-diversity)).

In activated B cells, however, [class switching](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2707252/) and [somatic hypermutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_hypermutation) can result in gross changes to the Ig locus not seen in immature or pro-B cells.